# Is there a pandas accessor for whatever is the underlying value in the object in each cell?

Tags: python, pandas, object, accessor

In the codebase I have pandas objects (`pd.DataFrame` / `pd.Series`) that contain custom objects.

It would simplify the codebase significantly if I could call a method or property from the underlying objects without resorting to `.apply`.

To illustrate the point, consider a pandas series of "Car" objects.

```
class Car:
   ...
   def max_speed(self)->float:
      ...

x = pd.Series([car1, car2, car3])
```

Currently I could get the average car speed by doing:

```
x.apply(lambda x: x.max_speed()).mean()
```

I think it'd be nice if I could skip the `.apply(lambda x: x...)` and replace it with something like:

```
x.obj.max_speed().mean()
```

where `obj` would be my custom accessor.

To further illustrate the point, consider a class `Plane`

```
class Plane:
    def cruise_height(self)->float:
```

In the codebase I have:

```
x1 = pd.Series([car1, car2, car3])
x2 = pd.Series([plane1, plane2, plane3])
```

and I could get the average car speed / plane cruise height with

```
x1.apply(lambda x: x.max_speed()).mean()
x2.apply(lambda x: x.cruise_height()).mean()
```

I think it'd be more readable if I could do:

```
x1.obj.max_speed().mean()
x2.obj.cruise_height().mean()
```

I imagine this would be similar to how `.str.` exposes the underlying string methods.

```
pd.Series(['Hello', 'World']).str.get(0) # returns ['H', 'W']
pd.Series(['Hello', 'World']).str.upper()
# etc
```

Comment: Is there any reason you don't simply declare `x = pd.Series([car1.max_speed, car2.max_speed, car3.max_speed])` and have a max_speed property on the class?

Comment: yes, this is a more general issue in the codebase (the code above is an example). I have a dataframe of semi-arbitrary objects (users, cars, planes, etc..). The access pattern `.apply(lambda x: x.max_speed)` or `.apply(lambda x: x.username)` is all over the code.

Comment: If you simply want to do a lot of (static) plotting of n objects x m attributes/properties (i.e. the values don't change during your plotting), you could put the values in an n x m array. But if you want to dynamically plot things, then maybe. It depends what the context of your code is; please show a bit more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Pandas documentation, you can register [custom accessors](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html#registering-custom-accessors) using special decorators, like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

@pd.api.extensions.register_series_accessor("spec")
class SpecAccessor:
    def __init__(self, pandas_obj: pd.Series):
        self._obj = pandas_obj
        for i in range(len(self._obj)):
            for attr in self._obj[i].__class__.__dict__:
                # set objects methods on the accessor
                if not attr.startswith("__"):
                    ser = pd.Series(
                        [getattr(self._obj[i], attr)() for i in range(len(self._obj))]
                    )
                    setattr(self, attr, ser)
```

So that with the following classes and instances:

```py
class Car:
    def __init__(self, speed: float):
        self._speed = speed

    def max_speed(self) -> float:
        return self._speed * 1.5

class Plane:
    def __init__(self, max_height: float):
        self._max_height = max_height

    def cruise_height(self) -> float:
        return self._max_height * 0.6

car1 = Car(10.0)
car2 = Car(30.5)
car3 = Car(50.9)

plane1 = Plane(5_000.0)
plane2 = Plane(3_000.5)
plane3 = Plane(9_000.9)
```

You can do:

```py
print(pd.Series([car1, car2, car3]).spec.max_speed)
# Ouputs
0    15.00
1    45.75
2    76.35
dtype: float64

print(pd.Series([plane1, plane2, plane3]).spec.cruise_height)
# Outputs
0    3000.00
1    1800.30
2    5400.54
dtype: float64
```